# CSS won't link to HTML

Tags: html, css

*(Beginner here...)*

My CSS won't link to my HTML. I am using GOORM IDE, I have read other questions on this topic and tried the solutions from them but none seem to work (when I apply the CSS inline, it works perfectly), I have so far tried:

- Moving the main.css to the same folder as the header.ejs file
- Adding type="text/css"
- Changing the href to:

main.css

/main.css

/stylesheets/main.css

/public/stylesheets/main.css

../stylesheets/main.css

None of which have worked. Any ideas? I want to keep the CSS in a separate folder if possible. I have included a screenshot of the file structure on GOORM also if that is useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! `Beginner here` we don't need to know that, a good question has nothing to do with one being a beginner. That being said, this looks like a duplicate.

Comment: i never heard of this ide.

Comment: _“I am using GOORM IDE”_ - not sure what that is; but assuming you still test the result in an normal browser, check what the browser console has to say.

Comment: What does your `main.css` actually contain, did you make sure it is _just_ the CSS? (A “popular” beginner’s mistake when moving inline styles to an external stylesheet, is to copy&paste the `<style>` tags into the CSS file as well, but those don’t belong there.)

Comment: @djangotic https://ide.goorm.io/

Comment: we need your config, how you build your ejs files? Your header.ejs inside 2 lvl folders, so you need ../../public/stylesheets/main.css

Comment: You know Goorm has a big Reddit help section linked from their website. As well as an extensive (but possibly rubbish) documentation. Have you tried these places for help? The things you've tried would / should work on a simple (ie non-goorm) set up

Comment: Assuming `public` is your HTML base folder; your CSS reference in a usual developement should be: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/main.css">`. As this doesn't work due to how Coorm compiles, I would recommend exploring the [Goorm help forum](https://www.reddit.com/r/goormIDE/)

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy thanks, the link you shared: "Can't get stylesheet to work with ejs for node.js" solved this perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

mmm I'm not sure really but I think your path based on the image should be

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">
```

Comment: If you're not sure, don't guess an answer. Node.js doesn't work that way.

Comment: :) am trying to help with what I know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also think, there should be the path to the .css-File.

for example, I called my css in the head like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app/css/app.css" />
```

So you need to call your file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="public/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

Btw: is the link to the fonts correct? Is this a valid repository?

Answer (score 0):

Tested in VSCode, this works for me:

You've got your header.ejs in views/partials and your main.css in public/stylesheets.

This means your link has to move up two directories. Use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../public/stylesheets/main.css>
```